# Calculating percentages in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL that has two columns of data, first is a week number, second is a value.  There can be multiple records for the same week.  Here's some sample data (I added some SQL for this data at the end):

| id | WeekNo | MyAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5200.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 180.00 |
| 3 | 1 | 100.00 |
| 4 | 2 | 100.00 |
| 5 | 2 | 50.00 |
| 6 | 3 | 100.00 |
| 7 | 3 | 100.00 |
| 8 | 4 | 100.00 |
| 9 | 4 | 900.00 |
| 10 | 4 | 1000.00 |

I have a query that sums these values by week, and adds another column that contains the cumulative value of all weeks.  This works OK

```
with data as (
    SELECT WeekNo,
           SUM(MyAmount) As TheAmount
    FROM #tTryIt
    GROUP BY WeekNo
    )

SELECT WeekNo, 
       TheAmount,
       SUM(TheAmount) over (order by WeekNo asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Cumulative
FROM data
```

| WeekNo | TheAmount | Cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5480.00 | 5480.00 |
| 2 | 150.00 | 5630.00 |
| 3 | 200.00 | 5830.00 |
| 4 | 2000.00 | 7830.00 |

Now what I am wanting to do is to calculate each week's value percentage against the cumulative, but to also include the previous week (eg if in week 2 the week 2 value is 25% then the week 1 value must be 75% of the cumulative total), however so far I have only been able to calculate the percentage for the current week, not the previous week(s).

Here is my current query and result:

```
with data as (
    SELECT WeekNo,
           SUM(MyAmount) As TheAmount
    FROM #tTryIt
    GROUP BY WeekNo
    )

SELECT WeekNo, 
       TheAmount,
       SUM(TheAmount) over (order by WeekNo asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Cumulative,
       (TheAmount/SUM(TheAmount) over (order by WeekNo asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row))*100 as WeekPct
FROM data
```

| WeekNo | TheAmount | Cumulative | WeekPct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5480.00 | 5480.00 | 100.000000 |
| 2 | 150.00 | 5630.00 | 2.664200 |
| 3 | 200.00 | 5830.00 | 3.430500 |
| 4 | 2000.00 | 7830.00 | 25.542700 |

But what I really need to get is something like this (where `WeekNo` is the actual week for the cumulative total, and the `PctWeek` is whichever week we're calulating the percentage for):

| WeekNo | PctWeek | TheAmount | Cumulative | WeekPct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5480.00 | 5480.00 | 100.0000 |
| 2 | 1 | 5480.00 | 5630.00 | 97.3358 |
| 2 | 2 | 150.00 | 5630.00 | 2.6642 |
| 3 | 1 | 5480.00 | 5830.00 | 93.9966 |
| 3 | 2 | 150.00 | 5830.00 | 2.5729 |
| 3 | 3 | 200.00 | 5830.00 | 3.4305 |
| 4 | 1 | 5480.00 | 7830.00 | 69.9872 |
| 4 | 2 | 150.00 | 7830.00 | 1.9157 |
| 4 | 3 | 200.00 | 7830.00 | 2.5544 |
| 4 | 4 | 2000.00 | 7830.00 | 25.5427 |

How can I actually go about getting my query to output the data I need?

---

Sample SQL data below

```
CREATE TABLE #tTryIt
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    WeekNo INT,
    MyAmount DECIMAL(18,2)
)

INSERT INTO #tTryIt

VALUES  (1, 1, 5200),
        (2, 1, 180),
        (3, 1, 100),
        (4, 2, 100),
        (5, 2, 50),
        (6, 3, 100),
        (7, 3, 100),
        (8, 4, 100),
        (9, 4, 900),
        (10, 4, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm not sure but if you do a `GROUP BY WeekNo` it's imposible to have the last example no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can take your query and then join it again with all the weeks.  This gives you the first three columns.  You can fill in the last two using window functions:

```
with data as (
      SELECT WeekNo, SUM(MyAmount) As TheAmount
      FROM TryIt
      GROUP BY WeekNo
     )
select w.weekno, d.weekno as pctweek, d.theamount,
       sum(d.theamount) over (partition by w.weekno) as cumulative,
       d.theamount * 100.0 / sum(d.theamount) over (partition by w.weekno)  as pct
from data d join
     (select distinct weekno from TryIt) w
     on d.weekno <= w.weekno
order by 1, 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c7413e24b334586e932fceed150681f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. The key here is to notice that the cardinality is increasing, implying a join of some sort is necessary.

```
   with thedata as (
    SELECT WeekNo,
           SUM(MyAmount) As TheAmount
    FROM tTryIt
    GROUP BY WeekNo
    )
    SELECT t1.WeekNo, 
           t2.WeekNo as PctWeek, 
           t2.TheAmount,
           SUM(if(t2.WeekNo=1,t1.TheAmount,0)) over (order by t1.WeekNo, t2.WeekNo asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Cumulative,
           t2.TheAmount/(SUM(if(t2.WeekNo=1,t1.TheAmount,0)) over (order by t1.WeekNo, t2.WeekNo asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row))*100 as WeekPct
    FROM thedata as t1 inner join thedata as t2 on (t2.WeekNo<=t1.WeekNo)
    order by t1.WeekNo, t2.WeekNo
    ;
```

It seems this yields the table you asked for:

```
| weekno | pctweek | theamount | cumulative | weekpct           |
+--------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| 1      | 1       | 5480      | 5480       | 100               |
| 2      | 1       | 5480      | 5630       | 97.33570159857904 |
| 2      | 2       | 150       | 5630       | 2.664298401420959 |
| 3      | 1       | 5480      | 5830       | 93.99656946826758 |
| 3      | 2       | 150       | 5830       | 2.572898799313894 |
| 3      | 3       | 200       | 5830       | 3.430531732418525 |
| 4      | 1       | 5480      | 7830       | 69.98722860791827 |
| 4      | 2       | 150       | 7830       | 1.915708812260536 |
| 4      | 3       | 200       | 7830       | 2.554278416347382 |
| 4      | 4       | 2000      | 7830       | 25.54278416347382 |
```